# Отправка писем пользователям с просроченной датой. Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

Ребята помогите доработать мой код. Нужно отправлять сообщения пользователям при истечении даты активности их в группе пользователей. Вот мой код:

```html
<?
global $USER;
$datenow = date($DB->DateFormatToPHP(CSite::GetDateFormat("FULL")), time());
$arfilter = Array(
            "ID" => $_REQUEST['MANAGER_ID'].' | '.$_REQUEST['USES_ID'],
   "UF_TO_KVALIF"=> "1",
            "GROUP_ID" => "7"
        );
        $arParameters = array(
            'SELECT' => array("UF_*")
        );
$rsUsers = CUser::GetList(($by="id"), ($order="asc"), $arfilter, $arParameters);
$is_filtered = $rsUsers->is_filtered; 
$rsUsers->NavStart(50); 
while($arUser = $rsUsers->Fetch()):
var_dump($arUser);

$res = CUser::GetUserGroupList($arUser["ID"]);
$ptime = getmicrotime();
while ($arGroup = $res->Fetch()){
$stmp = MakeTimeStamp($arGroup['DATE_ACTIVE_TO'], "DD.MM.YYYY HH:MI:SS");
 if ($ptime >= $stmp){
   CEvent::Send("client_del_kvalific", "s1", $arUser, "Y", 30);
  } 
var_dump($arGroup['DATE_ACTIVE_TO']);
}

endwhile;?>
```

Как правильно сравнить даты в массиве `$arGroup['DATE_ACTIVE_TO']` с текущей  датой `$ptime = getmicrotime();` чтобы каждому пользователю, у кого она просрочена приходило сообщение?

Comment: а чем вам не нравится ваше решение?

Comment: Oleksandr не работает условие, присылает уведомления пользователям всем, а не по условию

Comment: во-первых, зачем вам `getmicrotime`, если можно `time` ? 
во-вторых, у вас у всех пользователей у всех группах стоит дата окончания? подозреваю что есть и пустое поле, что в конечном варианте возвращает вам `true` в вашем условии.
Вам еще нужно проверять `&& empty($arGroup['DATE_ACTIVE_TO'])` или стрлен больше нуля... ну вы поняли логику.

Comment: Да у всех отфильтрованных пользователей мною стоит дата активности. `getmicrotime` для чтобы сразу текущее время возвращалось в UNIX-формате.

Comment: а `time()` в чем возвращает?
То-есть ваши пользователи принадлежат только к 1 группе? Даже к группе зарегистрированых не пренадлежит? Вы же в своей проверке берете все группы.

Comment: @Oleksandr нет, только пользователей которые принадлежат к 7-ой группе их id (`$arUser["ID"`]) передается в `CUser::GetUserGroupList($arUser["ID"])` и они правильно выводятся, их даты активности тоже. Но вот сравнить `$arGroup['DATE_ACTIVE_TO']`  и (например `$datenow = date($DB->DateFormatToPHP(CSite::GetDateFormat("FULL")), time());`) текущую дату сайта

Comment: 1. почему вы не используете фильтрацию mysql - сделайте запрос таким образом, чтобы получить всех пользователей с просроченой датой, а не сортируйте пыхой
2. вам нужна какая-то метка, что письмо уже ушло, чтобы не отправить письмо повторно. пример фильтрации - https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/support/forum/forum6/topic25811/

Comment: @myxaxa у битрикса тут модные фильтры, думал ими воспользоваться а не mysql. В логи уходит что сообщение отправлено. Мне сейчас важна сама конструкция правильная, а остольное прикручу.

Comment: @ЕвгенийПивоваров я имел ввиду, почему вы не фильтруете пользователей в CUser::GetList с подстановкой корректных значений, а делаете фильтрацию в цикле по всем полученным. в $arfilter['<=DATE_ACTIVE_TO'] = ConvertDateTime( date() ,  "YYYY-MM-DD" ) - типа того

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно использовать встроенную функцию `CDatabase::CompareDates` ([документация](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cdatabase/comparedates.php)).

Только, конечно, в `$ptime` вам надо записать `date('d.m.Y H:i:s')`, т.е. в формате, который использует Битрикс, и всё корректно сравнится.